# C# Get the calling method's, line number, class file and method name, etc, in the receiving method without parsing any variables or using references?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

(SOLVED)
I have my own *class library* that I've been successively developed, iterated and modified during my programming course, it contains a multitude of methods that I use on the regular. For example I have a method that is called from any *class* using the *class* with `B_Core.WriteDebug(string);`.
This method currently only takes whatever text I've written, and allows me to not include the `System.Diagnostics` in the classes using my own *library*.

This can, on occassion lead to situations where I simply want to know a single digit, and it could be something like `B_Core.WriteDebug(integer.ToString());`. As I've developed as a programmer I do try to always include a *reference point*, but when I miss it, I sometimes just get a *line* in the *Debug output* saying "4" or something along those lines.

So, I am currently trying to make a decent correction to this method. Currently the only idea I have is to parse a StackTrace to the method.

```cs
public static void WriteDebug(string text, StackTrace trace) {
    var frame = trace.GetFrame(0);
    string writeString = "Line: " + 
                            frame.GetFileLineNumber() + " | " + 
                            frame.GetFileName() + " | " + 
                            frame.GetMethod() + " | Text:\n";
    writeString += text;

    // Debug output => Line: x | File: Program.cs | Main | Text:
    //                 Hello world!
    Debug.WriteLine(writeString);
}
```

This'll work, but it requires me to add the `using System.Diagnostics` to each class that is gonna use the `B_Core.WriteLine()`. This can result in some pointless written additions, it's also the *class* granting easy accessibility to `Debug.WriteLine()`, which removes part of my reason for having my own method for this in the *library*.

It also requires me to actually parse the StackTrace, adding more things to write when I simply want to know a simple thing for troubleshooting or similar.

The ideal scenario would be something like:

```cs
public static void WriteDebug(string text) { //Removed the StackTrace parse
    var frame = Caller.trace.GetFrame(0);    //Added a hypothetical Caller object
    string writeString = "Line: " + 
                            frame.GetFileLineNumber() + " | " + 
                            frame.GetFileName() + " | " + 
                            frame.GetMethod() + " | Text:\n";
    writeString += text;

    // Debug output => Line: x | File: Program.cs | Main | Text:
    //                 Hello world!
    Debug.WriteLine(writeString);
}
```

Where I'd get the data by just referencing the calling method itself. So my question is there any way to do something like this without adding extra references atop the *calling method's class* as well as hopefully not having to parse any other *object* to the  *method*?

Thanks for any insight into this.

Best regards!

Solution, thanks to Fildor in the comments. The answer by Victor is also good and might be closer to the actual question. But I've decided to use Fildor's recommendation.

This is the method at this time:

```cs
public static void WriteTrace(string text, bool printTrace = true,
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string membName = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string filePath = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0) {

            
    if (printTrace) 
        Trace.Write("Line: " + 
            lineNumber + " | " + 
            filePath.Split('\\').Last() + " | " + 
            membName + ":\t"
        );
    Trace.WriteLine(text);
    //Output => Line: 208 | BMenu.cs | MoveSelection:   0
}
```

Comment: There are Attributes for that. [CallerMemeberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0), [CallerLineNumberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute?view=net-6.0) and [CallerFilePathAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-6.0)

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Another tip would be to use an actual Logging Framework.

Comment: @Fildor This worked perfectly. Still in C# basic programming, and I have other things that I need to focus on than figuring out how to add another framework at the moment :P

Comment: @Fildor Want to make it an answer so I can set it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Attributes:

FunctionName that called: [CallerMemeberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0)

Caller File: [CallerFilePathAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-6.0)

Caller Line Number: [CallerLineNumberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can get your hypothetical Caller object going up on the stack:

```
public static void WriteDebug(string text)
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(stackTrace.FrameCount - 2);

    string writeString = "Línea: " +
        frame.GetFileLineNumber() + " | " +
        frame.GetFileName() + " | " +
        frame.GetMethod() + " | Text:\n";
    writeString += text;

    // Salida de depuración => Línea: x | Archivo: Program.cs | Principal | Texto:
    // ¡Hola mundo!
    Debug.WriteLine(writeString);
}
```

`stackTrace.GetFrame(stackTrace.FrameCount - 1)` is the last frame, your `WriteDebug` method. Using the previous frame you are using the caller method.